# Why do you need a Hyper-V?

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v

Ok, I know what is basically a Hyper-V is.

Simple, a virtual machine. Well, good for testing application and development usage.

Ok, so far so good for the understanding. and here the main question:

Why do you need to install servers in a Hyper-V on a real server?
Isn't that running a server os on the real machine is somehow better performance than running it in a virtual environment?

for example, database server. Install it in a virtual machine? why not on the real machine?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, Hyper-v is a brand name, for Microsoft's hyper visor. (equally, VMWare and Xen are competing hyper visors) It sounds like you mean virtual machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One example of its use would be to create the perfect developer environment if you want to run many different versions of SQL Server on the same physical box.

SQL Server 2005 isn't compatible with Windows 10 so a virtual server running Windows 2003 is better to house it. Windows 2008 for SQL Server 2008 and so on.

This also gives you the flexibility to allocate resources to different VMs and prioritise RAM to the instance that your currently developing against. Giving you server level options with client tools running on the host OS as intended.

Check out this blog post on setting up such a dev environment.

http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/paul/2016/05/using-hyper-v-and-powershell-to-create-the-perfect-developer-workstation/